# How not to open the input on the phone in full screen when input in focus?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I tried a bunch of things and came to the conclusion that the problem is most likely due to fullpage.js . The section is a slider and when you click on input, the keyboard opens and the system adjusts the keyboard to the bottom of the input, but there is nowhere to go down.  It turns out that the content just goes beyond the screen and everything turns white. It is necessary to somehow allow scrolling and leave additional space for scrolling, but maybe someone knows how else to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. A great resource to use is [mcve]. This will help you ask questions in a way that allows users to assist you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of fullPage.js? v4.0.9?

Comment: Yes, there was the latest version. I solved the problem by displaying the input (feedback form) in the modal window